# python - writing into csv and returning its URL - missing CSV parts

Tags: python, django, csv

I have this (simplified for here) code:

```
csv_file = open('/'.join([settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'people.csv']), 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for person in Person.objects.all():
     writer.writerow(['name', 'blabla', 'blablablanbl'])
     writer.writerow(['adress', 'blabla', 'blablabla'])
     #... many other things

csv_file.close()
csv_url = 'http://' + request.META['HTTP_HOST'] + "/media/%s" % os.path.basename(csv_file.name)
```

Then I return the URL of newly written csv file to remote API endpoint, and that endpoint reads the csv file back into its database etc..

Now the thing is that sometimes the csv file is written correctly at my endpoint but the other endpoint gets incomplete csv file e.g. the last 3 rows are missing etc..

what am I missing here? do I need to make all steps "write-close-return" in an atomic way?